# Пробую запустить часть кода, но почему-то мне надо ввести лишнее значение, чтобы программа выдала результат

Tags: c, массивы

Пробую запустить часть кода, но почему-то мне надо ввести лишнее значение, чтобы программа выдала результат. Можно ли переписать так, чтобы пользователю не приходилось вводить лишний символ для выведения результата?
Программа должна просто записывать элементы массива, а потом выводить их.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int A[6][9];
    int t, ca;
    ca = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++)
            scanf("%d ", &A[i][l]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
        for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++)
            printf("%d ", A[i][l]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы программа сразу после ввода всех элементов массива выводила эти же элементы, но программа выводит только после того, как я введу любое значение после ввода элементов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите пробел в

```
scanf("%d", &A[i][l]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло